# How to swap elements on hover while dragging with jquery ui

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to swap elements with jQuery UI in the `over` callback function of `droppable`. The swapping itself works fine, but afterwards the object being dragged is displayed on the wrong position. Is there a possibility to recalculate the position after the swap?

See the following example:

```js
$(".dragme")
  .draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0,
    scroll: false
  })
  .droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
      // Get drag & drop elements
      var a = $(this);
      var b = $(ui.draggable);

      // Swap those elements
      var tmp = $('<span>').hide();
      a.before(tmp);
      b.before(a);
      tmp.replaceWith(b);

      // TODO: Refresh Position?
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 110px; height: 100px;">
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: turquoise;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: magenta;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: With `helper: clone` and `visible: false` as suggested by T J multiple swapping does not work if hovered over the original position:

```js
$(".dragme")
  .draggable({
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 0,
    scroll: false,
  helper: 'clone',
  start: function(e, ui) {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
  },
  stop: function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
  }
  })
  .droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
      // Get drag & drop elements
      var a = $(this);
      var b = $(ui.draggable);

      // Swap those elements
      var tmp = $('<span>').hide();
      a.before(tmp);
      b.before(a);
      tmp.replaceWith(b);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 110px; height: 100px;">
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: turquoise;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: magenta;"></div>
  <div class="dragme" style="display: inline-block; width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "swap"..? the position of elements in UI, or their position in DOM..?

Comment: Ideally I would like to "swap" their position in DOM, like shown in the code snippet. The example is simplified, but I need to combine this with some other js logic which depends on DOM updates. I guess with "position of elements in UI" you mean just changing position attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the element being dragged hidden and use a [helper](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-helper) element for the visual feedback while you manipulate the position of actual element in DOM. Since we don't manipulate the position of helper there won't be any positioning issues in UI.

One issue is that helper element will be injected in DOM during drag operation so you might want to filter it out from the rest of your code which depends on DOM

```js
$(".dragme")
  .draggable({
    revert: true,
    helper: "clone",
    revertDuration: 0,
    scroll: false,
    start: function(e, ui) {
      $(this).addClass('hidden');
    },
    stop: function() {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden');
    }
  })
  .droppable({
    over: function(event, ui) {
      // Get drag & drop elements
      var a = $(this);
      var b = $(ui.draggable);
      b.before(a);
    }
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.container {
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size:0;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.turq {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="box dragme red"></div>
  <div class="box dragme blue"></div>
  <div class="box dragme green"></div>
  <div class="box dragme turq"></div>
  <div class="box dragme magenta"></div>
  <div class="box dragme yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Can't swap with your swap routine though. If I add `helper: "clone"` to my solution, it works somehow, but if i swap multiple elements it won't swap if a new element is on the "original" position (hard to explain). For example, swap yellow with turquoise and then try to swap it back = won't work.

Comment: I added your suggestions to my original question.